# Write Host Variables to file in a loop with ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to build up a config file that contains the list of my inventory host servers and their fields eg. IP,FQDN etc.

Here is my part of inventory file :

```
ocp_cluster:
   hosts:
     anbootstrap.ocp.hattusas.tst:
         fqdn: anbootstrap.ocp.hattusas.tst
         ip: 10.72.217.92
     anmaster1.ocp.hattusas.tst:
         fqdn: anmaster1.ocp.hattusas.tst
         ip: 10.72.217.93
     anmaster2.ocp.hattusas.tst:
         fqdn: anmaster2.ocp.hattusas.tst
         ip: 10.72.217.94
     anmaster3.ocp.hattusas.tst:
```

And here is my playbook:

```
  - name: Adding OCP Clusters to DHCP configuration
    debug:
      "{{ hostvars[item][fqdn] }}"
    loop: "{{ groups['ocp_cluster'] }}"
```

(I will use blockinfile soon)

When I ran my playbook I am getting undefined error fqdn. I tried using a for loop and it didn't help. Any suggestions? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The fixed task is below

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[item]['fqdn'] }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['ocp_cluster'] }}"
```

- Debug parameter `msg` was missing
- `fqdn` is an attribute of a dictionary. It must be quoted in brackets. Similar to `ocp_cluster`.
- It's possible to use the [dot notation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names) and simplify the references to the attributes of the dictionaries

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[item].fqdn }}"
  loop: "{{ groups.ocp_cluster }}"
```